# Android - Global Layout Listener not working

Tags: android, layout, listener, android-softkeyboard

I used the code from Reuben Scratton's new answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android). When I paste it into my code, I get red squigglies underneath    `addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()`, `onGlobalLayout()`, and `activityRootView` (after heightDiff). Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Thanks
Here's my code on the .java page

```
public class Details extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Intent intent = getIntent();        
}


final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.details);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back); 
            backButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.hide_keyboard);
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Please don't try to learn programming Java and Android through copy/paste.  It's not a successful approach.  Go through the basics and start with "Hello World"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add that code inside a method, like `onCreate()`.

```
public class Details extends Activity {
    View activityRootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        Intent intent = getIntent();        

        activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.details);    
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back); 
                    backButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.hide_keyboard);
                }
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in my project the onGlobalLayout is called in a method in a normal class, and this method is called in onCreate method in a fragment, my problem is that when i debug the application, the block of the code under the onGlobalLayout is unreachable.

Comment: what if I'm using databinding? @Sam

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass You can call binding component's getRoot() method for root view of the layout.